# Android - changing textSize of TextView attached to ViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, textview, layout-manager, android-recyclerview

I use GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView for three different situation (1 column, 2 columns, 3 columns), but I also need change textSize of TextView attached to ViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter.

Activity code:

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(data);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

...

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

    protected TextView vName;
    protected ImageView vImage;
    protected ImageButton vButton;

    protected ProgressBar vProgress;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        vName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextViewGrid);
        vImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        vButton = (ImageButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.action_edit_grid);

        vProgress = (ProgressBar) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

    }
}
```

When i try:

```
TextView text = (TextView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
text.setTextSize(12);
```

Compiler return null reference. Any idea please?

Comment: Can you share your adapter code

Comment: Where trying to use `TextView text = (TextView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);` code?

Comment: In Activity, after initializing recyclerView, where is changing the number of columns in GridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good solution, thank you Devunwired for the direction. When I look to:

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/org/lucasr/twowayview/sample/LayoutAdapter.java

He pass **layoutId** to the constructor, so then i can call the new adapter:

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(data, numberOfColumns);
```

and then in CustomViewHolder in CustomAdapter:

```
...
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView vName;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        vName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);

        if (mLayoutId == 1) {
            vName.setTextSize(33);
        }
        else if (mLayoutId == 2) {
            vName.setTextSize(22);
        }
        else if (mLayoutId == 3) {
            vName.setTextSize(11);
        }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your looking in the wrong place. You wouldn't ask the parent `RecyclerView` for a reference to the `TextView` in each child, you need to get that from each individual child view.

It would seem like the simplest place to do so would be inside of `onCreateViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, viewGroup, false);

    TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextViewGrid);
    text.setTextSize(12);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

...or perhaps during the `ViewHolder` creation:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
    super(itemLayoutView);
    vName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextViewGrid);
    vImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    vButton = (ImageButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.action_edit_grid);

    vProgress = (ProgressBar) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

    vName.setTextSize(12);
}
```

This way it is set for each item view, but only during initial creation of the view.

Comment: You are right, but how to tell the adapter from Activity, that number of columns in GridLayoutManager has changed?